# Iterate for loop backwards?

Tags: ios, nsarray, iteration

I am pretty much trying to do the following line with backwards iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [thetableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
```

I know there is `reverseObjectEnumerator` but I am not sure how to integrate that into an array like this. Can anyone help me out here? I have looked through many other answers to no avail.

*Would this do it?*

```
for (int i = [thetableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1; i > -1; i--) {
```

Comment: You can start with i equal to the number of rows minus one, and use i-- to go backwards.

Comment: Check the code I just posted, would that do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int numberOfRows = [theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;

for (int i = numberOfRows; i >= 0; i--)
{

}
```

1. Set the variable to the number of rows, minus 1 (to account for the 0 base).
2. Set the condition to test if i is greater than or equal to 0. If the above condition is true,
3. Instead of adding 1 on each iteration, decrease by 1.